# XPath expression which selects NodeA if it exists, but otherwise fall back to NodeB

Tags: xpath

When parsing a POM file, I want to read `/project/groupId` if it exists. However, if it does not exists I want to read `/project/parent/groupId`. How can that be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have XPath 2.0 then it's easy:

```
(/project/groupId, /project/parent/groupId)[1]
```

---

In XPath 1.0 it's fiddlier because there's no notion of ordered sequences of nodes like you get in XPath 2.0 - you can build unions of node sets but positional predicates always refer to document order, so

```
(/project/groupId | /project/parent/groupId)[1]
```

would give you whichever of `/project/groupId` or `/project/parent/groupId` comes first in the XML document.

For this case you can use a trick based on the fact that when you treat a boolean as a number in XPath, true becomes 1 and false becomes 0:

```
substring(concat(/project/parent/groupId, /project/groupId),
          boolean(/project/groupId) * string-length(/project/parent/groupId) + 1)
```

To explain what this is doing, take an example - the parent groupId is "foo", the project groupId is "bar".  First we concatenate the two, parent first - "foobar".  Next we check whether the project groupId element exists, and since it does

- `boolean(/project/groupId) * string-length(/project/parent/groupId) + 1` = `3 + 1` = `4`

so we take the substring starting at the fourth character, giving the result "bar".

Now suppose the parent groupId was "foo" and there's *no* project groupId.  In this case

- `concat(/project/parent/groupId, /project/groupId)` is just "foo"
- `boolean(/project/groupId) * string-length(/project/parent/groupId) + 1` = `0 + 1` = `1`

Since the "substring starting from the first character" is the whole string, this gives the correct result of "foo".

---

P.S. remember you need to account for the namespace - Maven POM files usually declare `http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0` as the default namespace so you will need to use whatever mechanism your XPath library provides to either set this as the default namespace (if possible) or bind it to a suitable prefix and use paths like `/pom:project/pom:groupId`

Answer (score 0):

You may just check if the length of the resultig DOMNodeList for the "/project/groupId" Xpath query contains any node and if it does not run the "/project/parent/groupId" query.

It may probably be done in just one shot but I would need more info then.